# How to stop workflow in hybris?

Tags: java, workflow, sap-commerce-cloud

I participate in project which uses hybris.

I develop workflow. I want to configure it so:

after automated action I return decision and after it I want to stop workflow. I want to make something in another code and after it notify workflow for continue.

What do you think about it?

Is it real? I cannot to find how to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I would assign this action to some specific user (not used to log in at all).
Then in another part of code I would manipulate the workflow - decide for this user.

For instance WorkflowProcessingService will contain the following method:

```
void decideAction(WorkflowActionModel action, WorkflowDecisionModel decision);
```